# What can be used to lubricate a rattling fan?

Tags: cpu, fan

My CPU fan started acting up a while back, it was making this rattling noise while running, so to fix the problem I grabbed a can of WD-40, took the sticker off the fan, and sprayed a little on the ball bearing to get it lubricated.

The problem is fixed, but friends are telling me that WD-40 isn't meant to be used on ball bearings, is not really a lubricant, and the problem is likely to come back even worse than before.

With that in mind, what would you use to lubricate a rattling fan? I'm told motor oil is a better option, what do you guys think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What lubricants can be safely added to a laptop fan?](http://superuser.com/questions/1007968/what-lubricants-can-be-safely-added-to-a-laptop-fan).  Note: that question is newer but has many good upvoted answers so makes a better reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the fan. I've tried every lubricant known to man and they just buy you a few days or weeks. Once the fan starts rattling, the bearings are physically damaged. Lubricant can't fix that.